# Removing Elements from structure if they are blank so they are not displayed in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, delegates

I have a simple gym workout App that consists of 2 view controllers (vc1 and vc2).
Users put some information into VC2, this is then this is passed to and displayed in VC1.
VC1 is a UITableView. The information in VC2 is stored in a struct and passed to VC1 via protocol delegate method. 
The user inputs data in VC2 to fill the struct. Then VC1 populates itself based on the struct.

VC1 is an extendible UITableView. Users put in the title of the workout and then when the row is clicked the users can see the exercises that they entered along with their sets and reps.
my plan is to have 10 exercises sections that the users can enter.

My problem is that if the user doesn't want a workout to consist of 10 exercises, say they want the workout to consist of only 3 exercisers. So they will fill in the fields for 3 exercises only. I am left with 3 cells in the UITableView that are populated with information and 7 that are occupied by black strings.

How can I get rid of the 7 blank exercises so they will not show up in the UITableView? In this code below I have only added one exercise element not 10 yet. I just want to solve this issue first while the code isn't too big.

VC1 is called ContactsController this is the UITableView:

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    private let reuseidentifier = "Cell"

    struct cellData {
var opened = Bool()
var title = String()
var sectionData = [String]()
    }

    //here
    struct Contact {
var fullname: String
var excerciseOne: String
var excerciseOneReps: String
var excerciseOneSets: String
    }

    class ContactController: UITableViewController {

//new
var tableViewData = [cellData]()
var contacts = [Contact]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.title = "Workouts"

     //     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(handleAddContact))


    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier)

}


@IBAction func handleAddContact(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = AddContactController()
    controller.delegate = self

    self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller), animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//UITABLEVIEW
//all new
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //new
    return tableViewData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //old needed return contacts.count

    //new
    if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
        return tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1
    }else {
        return 1
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //old needed    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath)
    //               cell.textLabel?.text = contacts[indexPath.row].fullname
    //    return cell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
        return cell
    }else {
        //use a different cell identifier if needed
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath)
        // cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row - 1]
        return cell
    }
}



//did select row new
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) //play around with animation
    }else {
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) //play around with animation
    }
        }
    }

    //this is an extention to addContactController. this is what happens whent he done button is clicked in addcontactcontroller

    extension ContactController: AddContactDelegate {
func addContact(contact: Contact) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.contacts.append(contact)

        self.tableViewData.append(cellData.init(opened: false, title: contact.fullname, sectionData: [contact.excerciseOne + "      Reps: " + contact.excerciseOneReps + "      Sets: " + contact.excerciseOneSets, "cell2", "cell3"]))


    self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    }
```

The Following is my VC2 where the user inputs the data to create a workout and its associated exercises:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//here
protocol AddContactDelegate {
func addContact(contact: Contact)
}



class AddContactController: UIViewController {

//delegate
var delegate: AddContactDelegate?

//Title TextField
let titleTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "What you you like to call your workout?"
    tf.textAlignment = .center
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tf
}()

//Exercise 1 title TextField
let excercise1TextField: UITextField = {
    let ex1 = UITextField()
    ex1.placeholder = "What excercise are you doing?"
    ex1.textAlignment = .center
    ex1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ex1
}()

//Exercise 1 title TextField
let excercise1RepsTextField: UITextField = {
    let ex1Reps = UITextField()
    ex1Reps.placeholder = "Reps"
    ex1Reps.textAlignment = .center
    ex1Reps.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ex1Reps

}()

//Exercise 1 title TextField
let excercise1SetsTextField: UITextField = {
    let ex1Sets = UITextField()
    ex1Sets.placeholder = "Sets"
    ex1Sets.textAlignment = .center
    ex1Sets.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ex1Sets

}()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //making scroll view
    let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screensize.width
    let screenHeight = screensize.height
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 2000)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)


    //setting up how view looks-----
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    //top buttons
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDone))

   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))



    //view elements in scrollview
    //Workout Title label
    let workoutTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 25))
    workoutTitleLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2 , y: view.frame.height / 20)
    workoutTitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    workoutTitleLabel.text = "Workout Title"
    workoutTitleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    scrollView.addSubview(workoutTitleLabel)


    //workout title textfield
    scrollView.addSubview(titleTextField)
    titleTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
      //  textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
        titleTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor ,constant: -350),
        titleTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 64)
        ])
   titleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()



    //excercise 1 the locked in title Label
    let excersice1label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    excersice1label.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2 , y: view.frame.height / 5)
    excersice1label.textAlignment = .center
    excersice1label.text = "Excercise 1"
    excersice1label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    scrollView.addSubview(excersice1label)

    //excercise 1 title textField
    scrollView.addSubview(excercise1TextField)
    excercise1TextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        excercise1TextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
        //  textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
        excercise1TextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor ,constant: -220),
        excercise1TextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 64)
        ])
    excercise1TextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    //excercise 1 Reps textField
    scrollView.addSubview(excercise1RepsTextField)
    excercise1RepsTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        excercise1RepsTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
        //  textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
        excercise1RepsTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor ,constant: -190),
        excercise1RepsTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 64)
        ])
    excercise1RepsTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    //excercise 1 Sets textField
    scrollView.addSubview(excercise1SetsTextField)
    excercise1SetsTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        excercise1SetsTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
        //  textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
        excercise1SetsTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor ,constant: -160),
        excercise1SetsTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 64)
        ])
    excercise1SetsTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

}






   //done button
    @objc func handleDone(){
    print("done")

    //setting the uitextfields to the the contact
    guard let fullname = titleTextField.text, titleTextField.hasText else {
        print("handle error here")
        return
    }

    /* guard might be needed if a certain element is left empty
    guard let excerciseOne = excercise1TextField.text, excercise1TextField.hasText else {
        print("handle error here")
        let excerciseOne = "empty"
        return
    }
     */

    //setting the user input elements to to the contact so it can be passed to vc1 and presented
    let excerciseOne = excercise1TextField.text
    let excerciseOneReps = excercise1RepsTextField.text
    let excerciseOneSets = excercise1SetsTextField.text

    let contact = Contact(fullname: fullname, excerciseOne: excerciseOne!, excerciseOneReps: excerciseOneReps!, excerciseOneSets: excerciseOneSets!)
    delegate?.addContact(contact: contact)
    print(contact.fullname)

    }



    //cancel button
    @objc func handleCancel(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil )
    }

    }
```

Comment: Don't have discrete properties for the exercises.  Have an array of `Exercise` structs where that struct has `name`, `reps` and `steps` properties. You then use this array to provide the data for the tableview. Then if the user has 1 exercise or 1000 exercise in their workout, it makes no difference.  You will need to redesign your VC2 so that it has a text field for the workout name, a table view for the exercises and an "add button" to add a new exercise.

Comment: Am I living in future? Coz I asked a similar question moments ago BDW, happy new year,